# How to access to Windows localhost on iOS 10.3.3

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, safari, localhost

We are developing a Progressive Web Application and we would like to preview changes on Safari on my phone before building it. However, we have issues accessing our localhost website (on Windows 10) on my iPhone 6.

It worked on an iPhone connected to the same Wifi with iOS 11.X doing :

```
ng serve --open --host=0.0.0.0
```

and then writing in safari :

```
my.computer.ip:4200
```

But with iOS 10.3.3, this method seems to be blocked by Apple because we can only see the **background-color**, and the **website's name**.

We have tried to this method :

```
https://<computer_name>.local
```

We have also tried **localtunnel**, works fine with Android and Windows but still not on iOS 10.3.3 iPhone.

It seems to be iOS and not Safari because it doesn't work with Chrome neither.

Hope we will find a solution because we have to build everytime to check if changes work.

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: Well, that is the difficulty... I don't know how to check logs on the mobile version of Safari

Comment: Do you have access to a Mac? https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

Comment: No... that's the problem

Comment: What about using Chrome’s developer tools to set the user agent and browser window size to mobile safari?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 -port 4200 --disable-host-check
```

The disable host check flag should only be used for development.

Comment: I’m suspecting something. Do you have a way of testing the application on safari 10.x? It might not be an issue with the connection itself but with the app running on a previous version of safari. It wouldn’t be the first time :)

Comment: How could I check my Safari mobile version number ?

Comment: It usually matches the iOS major version. So in iOS 10 you would have safari 10 ( talking about major versions ). So I’m suspecting you might have issues with the browser itself. Did you check the console for any errors?

Comment: Like said before I can't have access to the console given that I have no access to Safari on a Mac. But in Chrome it does exactly the same thing...

Comment: Just a quick reminder that chrome on iOS or OS X is not the same as chrome in windows. It’s based on the safari. So it can have similar behaviour. But if you don’t have access to the console it makes it harder

Comment: Is firefox based on Safari too ?

Comment: To be more precise when I said based in Safari I meant based on WebKit. I believe Firefox on iOS also runs on WebKit due to iOS security restrictions. They might have changed that recently